# JCStress - strange volatile and static keyword behavior

Tags: java, concurrency, static, volatile, jcstress

I have this simple Jcstress test:

```
package io.denery;


import org.openjdk.jcstress.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jcstress.infra.results.IIII_Result;

@JCStressTest
@Outcome(expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING)
@State
public class RaceIRIWTest {
    volatile int x, y;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
            x = 1;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2() {
            y = 1;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor3(IIII_Result r) {
            r.r1 = x;
            r.r2 = y;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor4(IIII_Result r) {
            r.r3 = y;
            r.r4 = x;
    }
}
```

But the result of this test is:

> [OK] io.denery.RaceIRIWTest
> (JVM args: [-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+WhiteBoxAPI, -XX:-RestrictContended, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=RU, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant, -XX:-TieredCompilation, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM, -XX:+StressIGVN])
> Observed state   Occurrences              Expectation  Interpretation
> 0, 0, 0, 0    22,180,923   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 0, 0, 1       721,581   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 0, 1, 0        13,347   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 0, 1, 1       456,971   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 1, 0, 0       344,068   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 1, 0, 1            36   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 1, 1, 0       528,641   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 0, 1, 1, 1       258,265   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 0, 0, 0       204,088   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 0, 0, 1       667,580   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 0, 1, 1        94,877   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 1, 0, 0       663,159   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 1, 0, 1       306,251   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 1, 1, 0       128,608   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING
> 1, 1, 1, 1    18,838,186   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING

we see race condition, but if i put `static` to `volatile int x, y` and remove `volatile` keyword then the result of jcstress test will be:

> [OK] io.denery.RaceIRIWTest
> (JVM args: [-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+WhiteBoxAPI, -XX:-RestrictContended, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=RU, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant, -XX:-TieredCompilation, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM, -XX:+StressIGVN])
> Observed state   Occurrences              Expectation  Interpretation
> 1, 1, 1, 1   100,299,061   ACCEPTABLE_INTERESTING

Why doesn't volatile fix the race condition, but the static keyword fixes it? Or it is a Jcstress issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a JCStress expert.

But what you are missing is that you need to specify the legal outcomes, see the below link for an example.

https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/concurrency/mutex/Mutex_02_DekkerAlgorithm.java

[forbidden case]

In the case of the IRIW test, you want to prevent that stores made by different CPU's to different addresses, can be seen out of order. So you want to prevent that actor 3 sees `r1=1, r2=0` (so sees `x` before `y`). And actor 4 sees `r3=1, r4=0` (so sees `y` before `x`). So the forbidden case would be `1,0,1,0`

[volatile]

When I check the results with volatile, the forbidden case is not encountered. The reason is that the example with volatile is free of data races and hence it only produces sequential consistent (SC) executions. With SC there is always some total order over the loads/stores that explains the execution. Because there is a total order, it will also order stores to different addresses issued by different CPUs. Also SC will prevent the loads being reordered since an SC execution needs to be consistent with program order (PO).

[static without volatile]

The example with the static contains a data race since there is no happens before edge between the read and the write. So with static only it is allowed to see the forbidden execution `1,0,1,0`

A trivial explanation would be that the 2 loads get reordered by the JIT or CPU if it would allow for out of order loads (e.g. ARM). My guess is that you only see `1,1,1,1` because `x` and `y` are not unset by JCStress; but I don't know JCStress well enough.

[superfluous]

To make the example more interesting I would make the 2 stores opaque stores and the loads opaque loads and put a [LoadLoad] fence between the 2 loads to make sure they get executed in order. Opaque will make sure that the load/store don't get optimized out and it will provide atomicity (basic guarantees) but won't provide any ordering guarantees with respect to loads/stores to different addresses. So you will be testing the memory consistency guarantees of the CPU.

IRIW should not fail on modern CPUs since they are multi copy atomic, the only CPU I know of that could exhibit the behavior is the PowerPC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried all of your situations including [superfluous] part (Using VarHandles). So there are so many results (0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 1... etc.) excluding 1, 0, 1, 0 because i have 2 CPUs on my computer and 4 threads switching between them causes these results?